# Exchange ActiveSync support for Gmail in Android Lollipop

Tags: android, gmail

Google has stopped supporting Exchange ActiveSync for Gmail sometime back with the exception of Google Apps for business. However, one of the Android forum says that the Gmail 5.0 will support exchange. Does this mean with the Android Lollipop, Google has again started using Exchange ActiveSync for Gmail? The Android Lollipop documentation does not mention about this.

Answer (score 0):

The Gmail 5.0 Exchange support refers to the Android Gmail app supporting Exchange ActiveSync (EAS), not the Gmail service supporting EAS.